# Facing issue to put values in chat page , php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, database

Well , i'm trying to build a chat page related to db , php

So like this SQL goes like this

```
$sql = "SELECT message, ticketid, Sender FROM Messages WHERE ticketid = '$id' ";
```

I got this page to put the values (values inside are written in the script)
[Chat page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs3a3.png)
How am i supposed to put the values like this , and make like , Messageb y the sender ,  shows like the sender , message incoming , shows the message of admin

Comment: use mysql case to select who is sender and who is receiver.

Answer (score 0):

The user must log in to your site before using chat, so then use his sessionId to get the username and print it at all places you like.

Answer (score 0):

I would need more information about the tables of your database, but you could try to have a table that stores messages from the client and from the admin. This table should have an attribute with a Boolean type that determines if the message belongs to the client or to the admin.

```
CREATE TABLE Messages (message VARCHAR(255), ticketid INT, sender INT, isFromAdmin BOOLEAN)
```

Then you would call the sql query

```
$sql = "SELECT message, ticketid, Sender, isFromAdmin FROM Messages WHERE ticketid = '$id' ";
```

Then by checking if the value of isFromAdmin is true or false, you can style the message accordingly.

```
$result= $db->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      $style = $row["isFromAdmin"];
      if($style){
         $style = 'admin';
      }else{
         $style = 'client';
      }
      echo "<div class='".$style."'>".$row["message"]."</div>";
}else{
   echo "No rows found!";
}
```

You can then style the messages by using the class .admin or .client.
I hope this helps :)